# android development screen flow logic

Tags: android

in android, who takes care of the screens flow?

A screen closes after an operation and another screen opens. Which screen will be opened is a result of a complex logic.

I tried to do the flow in service, passing views as parameters to service methods, to let the service decide in which case will the screen close and started new activities from services to decide which screen will be displayed next.

But sometimes the screen needs to be closed/updated without user interaction (example a pending operation is complete), so there's no calling a service method, in that case I used broadcasts from service, and activities as broadcast listeners.

I guess the norm is handling flow in activities but doesn't that give a lot of responsibility to them? They are both aware of the layout components and app flow logic. In that case, when I need to reuse a screen, should I only reuse the layout.xml file with a different activity?

to me, it feels like the flow of screens is part of the business logic, so it shouldn't be inside controllers (activities).

I wrote some android back in school but that was only to save the day, so whatever worked I didn't mess with.